# PHP mail adds ';' to URL

Tags: php, url, cron

We have a cronjob running in our mail server which gives us a URL.
The code (of the URL) is:

```
<a href=\"http://example.com/?page=show_user&id=".$account->ID."\">http://example.com/?page=show_user&id=".$account->ID."</a>
```

When the cronjob progresses and we get the mail, the URL shows up like:

```
http://example.com/?page=show_user&id;=1
```

So the cron adds an additional `;` the code which we don't want.

I tried this already:

```
http://example.com/?page&#61;show_user&id&#61;
```

But still no success.  Is there any way to 'strip' that semicolon or prevent it appearing?

Comment: Post the actual PHP code of your `<a href` line

Comment: It's the same, I only changed 'domain' because of privacy reasons.

Comment: nope it isn't a valid PHP statement, need to see the complete statement like echo or something and where it terminates

Comment: is this caused by ur mail clients, i had a problem like this where URL's were being incorrectly parsed by the email clients but when echo'ed out the URL looks corrects. Maybe "\" at the end of the href is causing ur issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that cron job tries to handle &id as HTML entity (which should always end with ";").
Maybe you should use HTML entities in HTML code, so cron job will recognize them.

URL should be

```
<a href=\"http://domain.com/?page=show_user&amp;id=".$account->ID."\">http://domain.com/?page=show_user&amp;id=".$account->ID."</a>
```